# Textbox com valor pré-setado, mas também editável no c#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Estou com uma aplicação de cálculos, e tenho as seguintes situações:
Em um textbox tenho um valor pré-setado nos códigos para realizar um calculo com outro form que eu digito o valor, por ex: o textbox 1 soma com o textbox2.
E estou com dificuldade para escrever o código para quando se eu quiser alterar o valor no texbox1, pois ele lê apenas o valor que estava inserido no código e não o valor que eu insiro quando esta rodando o programa.

Segue o código abaixo:

OBS.: O código está apenas com o valor pré-setado.
Não consegui fazer a lógico de como editar o textbox quando estiver rodando o programa.

```
private void txtValor1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valor1 = double.Parse((txtValor1.Text = ("100")).ToString());
        }

private void txtValor2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            valor2 = double.Parse((txtValor2.Text).ToString());
        }

private void txtResult_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode ==Keys.Enter)
            {
                resultado = valor1 + valor2;
                txtResult.Text = resultado.ToString();
            }
        }
```

A foto abaixo mostra que quando eu inicio o programa, o `Valor 1` no `txtValor1` já aparece e apenas necessito digitar o `Valor 2` no `txtValor2`, `Valor 3` é o campo do resultado do cálculo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: explique melhor? se quer fazer o que?

Comment: @novic Eu preciso que o txtValor1, seja editável quando estiver rodando o programa para eu poder alterar o valor. 
Pois o valor "100" é fixo, mas também se caso necessitar eu conseguir alterar o valor no textbox.

Comment: Mas você digita e acontece oque?

Comment: no evento do txb1 você está definindo o valor pra 100... então sempre será 100... se quer definir só na hora que o programa iniciar, você tem que colocar no evento load do form ou após a inicialidação dos componentes no construtor do form.

Comment: aproveita e pesquisa pelo tryparse, porque se o usuário digitar um caractere não numérico vai dar erro de conversão no Parse e crashar a aplicação

Comment: @novic Eu não consigo digitar, ele não altera o valor.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Ah então eu defino ele apenas no load do form, mas mesmo eu definindo no load do form ele calcula normalmente com o valor de 100?
Eu coloquei o try catch e coloquei exceções para apenas digitar caracteres numéricos.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Inseri no evento Load do form. E eu tenho que inserir no txt1: ```valor1 = double.Parse((txtValor1.Text).ToString());``` 
Pois apenas apenas inserindo no Load, não ele deixa eu alterar o txt1.

Comment: sim, tirar a atribuição `txtValor1.Text = ("100")` que você fez no evento... 
| sobre o try....me referi ao tryparse: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.5 | você também pode fazer o cálculo tudo em um evento só... sem precisar pressionar uma tecla no txb do resultado

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Coloquei o código no Load do form, mas quando eu quero alterar o valor ele não apaga o valor inserido no Load. 
Porque estaria acontecendo isso? Alguma dica?
A sim, entendi sobre TryParse e já alterei para calcular tudo junto.

Comment: no evento do textbox, você está atribuindo o valor no campo...apaga isso.... `valor1 = double.Parse((txtValor1.Text = ("100")).ToString());` .... `(txtValor1.Text = ("100")` é uma atribuição

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Deu certo!
Muito obrigada pela ajuda!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O mais fácil seja talvez usar uma propriedade que retorne sempre o valor da soma dos dois campos.
Desta forma heis a minha proposta. Pode ser melhorada e para ser mais robusto, devia-se usar o TryParse ao invés do Parse.

```
public double valorCalculado 
{
    get
    {
        if(txtValor1.Text.Lenght > 0 && txtValor2.Text.Lenght > 0)
            return double.Parse((txtValor1.Text)) + double.Parse((txtValor2.Text));
        else if(txtValor1.Text.Lenght > 0)
            return double.Parse((txtValor1.Text));
        else if(txtValor2.Text.Lenght > 0)
            return double.Parse((txtValor2.Text));
        else
            return 0.0;
    }
}

private void txtValor1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Recalcular();
}

private void txtValor2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Recalcular();
}

private void txtResult_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode ==Keys.Enter)
    {
        Recalcular();
    }
}

private void Recalcular()
{
    txtResult.Text = valorCalculado.ToString();
}
```

Quanto aos valores presetados, apenas colocar eles no construtor.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Após as ajudas recebidos eu consegui entender para deixar o valor pré-setado. É necessário inserir no load.
Logo eu apaguei do meu evento **TextChanged** e coloquei no evento **LOAD** do formulário.

```
        private void frmCalculo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           valor1 = double.Parse((txtValor1.Text = ("100")).ToString());
        }
```